# High Memory Usage on Replica - Mysql 8

Tags: mysql, replication, memory, mysql-8.0, master-slave-replication

Hope you're doing well.

We've recently moved to Mysql 8 (from Mysql 5.7).

We're using AWS RDS Service with MySql. The AWS Team is also looking for a solution btw.

Since a few days, we're facing several problem with replication. We never met these problems before with the 5.7 version.

First, we had a very import lag among our Master and our two replicas.

This was solved with specifics params on the Parameters group of the replica like :

- slave_parallel_type in LOGICAL_CLOCK mode
- binlog_group_commit_sync_delay with a 10ms delay
- sync_binlog at 0

It seems that the latency is now gone, and it's a good news (i'll wait several days to be sure).

Nevertheless, we're still facing a massive problem with the RAM used on the Replica.

We can't find the problem, perhaps the buffer, but it must be locked with a threshold.

It's a cycle movement like this :

[image: High Memory usage on replica versus Production]

In Green, the production.

In Orange the small replica.

In Blue the most powerfull replica (As you can see, we tried to upgrade the instance, but it's not a RAM limitation problem).

The problem is the same for both. The memory usage is increasing till the replica has to down.

By the way, the swap is never used.

If you have any clue with this, it will help me a lot!

Thanks for reading!

Have a nice day :)

--- UPDATE ---

It seems that the buffer is full, but I don't know with what.
Is there any garbage collector running ? Because seems not, perhaps something to turn on with Mysql8?

Here some queries showing the size of the allocated memory and a zoom on the innodb memory repartition. We see that I Have 12go on this replica. And they must be full if the memory is decreasing :

> ```
>  SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(event_name,'/',2) AS
>    code_area, FORMAT_BYTES(SUM(current_alloc))
>    AS current_alloc
>    FROM sys.x$memory_global_by_current_bytes
>    GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(event_name,'/',2)
>    ORDER BY SUM(current_alloc) DESC;
> ```

[image: Result of First Query]

> ```
>    SELECT *
>    FROM sys.x$memory_global_by_current_bytes
>  WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(event_name,'/',2) = "memory/innodb"
>    ORDER BY current_alloc DESC
>  LIMIT 10;
> ```

[image: Result of Second Query]

Comment: What values do you have for these (on each server):  `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup';` and `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_buffer_pool_dump%''` ?

Comment: Hello Rick,
Thanks for answering.

On the main server for your first query the Value is `"ON"`.

For the second query the values are :

`innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown ON`
`innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now OFF`
`innodb_buffer_pool_dump_pct 25`

Exact same values for the Replica Server.

Answer (score 0):

```
innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup = ON
```

Tells the server to reload the buffer_pool at startup.  This causes a lot of I/O in a short period of time.

Its goal is to make the subsequent queries a little faster, but that may or may not be worth it.

If this is a cloud service, they probably do some regular maintenance, perhaps a backup, at the about the same time every day.

As a compromise, drop this to 10 (percent):

```
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_pct
```

That will cut back on the I/O while still giving some of the pre-loading benefits.

What is the size of all the data?  Perhaps the buffer_pool is unnecessarily large?

Comment: Hello Rick,  Thanks for the Tips! For the data, i've there about 200GO of data in this database, what do you think?

Comment: 200G is relatively large.  I assume (without any proof) that the "pct" gives preference to non-leaf nodes of the various BTrees.  This would give a good tradeoff.